# Get RadGrid Selected Item Row Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radgridview

I have a RadGrid and one of the columns contains an ASP button.

I'm using the following code:

```
GridDataItem RowNo = (sender as Button).Parent.Parent as GridDataItem;    
int index = RowNo.RowIndex;
```

Now if I click them, the button in the **1st** row's result should come as **0**, the button in the **2nd** row's **result** should come as **1**, and so on.

But the code I'm using is returning values as **1** for the **first** row, **2** for the **second** row...

How can I get the actual index of the row of which button I'm clicking?

Comment: Have you tried ItemIndex instead of RowIndex?

Comment: OK I will post it as an answer

Comment: On a side note, you should use NamingContainer instead of Parent.Parent. This uses the container that implements INamingContainer, which is the grid item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  ItemIndex instead of RowIndex

Comment: Caqn you explain  me a little bit more about the naming container? I know nothing about it.. Thanks :)